# Issue with Bar Height on D3 Grouped Chart Implementation

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to make a d3 grouped bar chart. Here is what i have so far:
http://jsbin.com/sobuv/2/

The problem I am currently stuck on is how the heights of my bars is not matching the values in the y axis.  For example in the first set "Jan" the values are 33.98,  40.1, 60.1 but I only set the height.

What am i doing wrong here - probably i guess around these lines?

```
.transition()
   .duration(500)
     .attr("y", parseInt(h, 10) - value)
     .attr("height", value);
```

I'd appreciate a hand here i'm sure its something simple which is eluding me. Thanks!

Comment: You're creating x and y scales to draw the axes, but are never using them when you draw your rectangles.  Look at this tutorial for an explanation of scales with bar charts: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html

Comment: What am i not understanding about scales then? Should y(value) return the height in proportion to the scales for that value?

Comment: Ok I think i got it...http://jsbin.com/sobuv/3 But why is that one value for Mar not showing?

Comment: Your scale domain was defined as `[min, max+50]`, so that means that your minimum value was being graphed right at your axis line -- i.e., a height of zero.  You need to set the y domain as `[0, max]` for a bar graph.  But you should also really spend some time going through those tutorials -- you're not taking advantage of any of d3's features for making your programs simpler by joining the data to your elements.  In addition to [Mike Bostock's introduction](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/), I would recommend [Scott Murray's tutorials](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/).

Comment: Really this is the answer to the question.. Thanks I'm having a read of the tutorials again to see what i can do better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Recap from the comments)*

If you're used to using statistical or spreadsheet graphing programs, you may expect that your graphics will be drawn according to the scales created when you declared the max and min values for your axes.  That's not how it works with d3.  Every element is drawn separately as an SVG graphical object, and if you give it size or position values those will be interpretted as pixel values (or transformed SVG coordinates if you've used any graphical transformations).

[D3 scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Scales) are used to manage the relationship between data values and on-screen pixels.  You set the domain of the scale according to your data values, and the range of the scale according to the pixel values you want to use for that data.  For linear (numerical) scales, the domain and range are defined as two-element arrays -- the first value in the range will be the pixel value for data equal to the first value in the domain, the second value in the range will be the pixel value for the second value in the domain, and every other value will be calculated in proportion to those.

But simply creating the scale isn't enough.  The scale object is a *function* -- you pass in a value as a parameter, and it returns the pixel value that you should use to set width, height, x and y positions for your SVG elements.

Good introductions to d3:

- Mike Bostock's ["Let's Make a Bar Chart"](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/) — scales are introduced in [part 2](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html)
- Scott Murray's [D3 Tutorials](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/) (and his book developed from them) — scales are introduced in [ch. 15](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/scales)
- And many more [listed on the d3 wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials)